# Meteor: use of cursor defined in the helper for events of the same template

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a template, newThings. The template finds all Things that are new and display them on my webpage. This is done. But then I wanted to add a "submit" button to the template, and by clicking the button all the new Things are going to be inserted into a collection in the Mongo db. How do I do this?

In more detail, the helper of Template.newThings returns a cursor: `return ThingsCollection.find({Checked: true})`, which I then use the "#each" tag to surface on the webpage. I then use a checkbox to allow users to uncheck any item. So far so good. When the user is done with checking/unchecking, they click the "submit" button and I intend to insert everything that's still checked into a collection called "GroupsCollection". I try to define a function in Template.newThings.events for the button click, then how do I reference those items to be inserted? I tried "this", it's empty; I tried citing the name of the helper, "newitems" and it returns the undefined error. A more general question  is: is my approach "meteor-like"? Should I have tried to accomplish this differently?

If needed I can post more code but I hope the above is sufficient information, because it's a somewhat general question.

Comment: just add the checked template so i can give you a better example.

Comment: You meant the code about the template, the helpers and the events? Can't do it now. Don't have code with me. Sync issue. They are just a few lines of code, very simple. Does exactly what I described above

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with simple jquery and $.each example

```
<div>
    <p>some data</p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
</div>
<div>
    <p>some data2</p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
</div>
<div>
    <p>some data3</p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
</div>
```

in the helper

```
Template.sometemplate.events({
  'click .submit' : function() {
     $('.check').each(function() {
       if($(this).prop('checked')){
         Meteor.call('somemethod',$(this).parent().find('p').text());
       }         
    })
  }
})
```

this just an example it can be done with many ways.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this when I get hold of my code. What other ways are you referring to?

Comment: its actually based on your setup how you get your data,your structure,your other events for example if when a user checks a checkbox you might add a class and then only get that class. etc.

Comment: What does the `find('p')` do here? Does it also result in a cursor like in the helper? If so, can I use `find({checked:true})` like in the helper?

Comment: @MichM it actually finds the p its a simple jquery command so you get the text of this p that the input is checked.In the example above we find all the  checked inputs by selecting their class `$('.check').each(function() {` and then see which of them are checked `if($(this).prop('checked')){`.and then getting the text of the nearest p and pass the data to a meteor method.it would be easier if you post your template to find a solution for you.

Comment: I see what you mean. The newThing however is not just text. They are items in an existing collection. When they are checked, they form a group. When a user clicks "submit", the group gets recorded: recording each newThing's id in that existing collection of Things. So going back to the html to obtain the attributes (e.g. text) of a Thing sounds like it would not take into consideration that they are exiting items and the collection of Groups have an underlying relationship with the collection of Things... Is there an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: Would two-way binding be the way to go?

Comment: it was just an example  the text,sure there is a way you can add them in an object and pass them like that in your collection.Add some of your code  if you want a better example.